# Significant interaction but no significant simple effects in lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme, interaction, interpretation

In my liner mixed effect model, there are two independent variables `location` (2 factors: E, word) and `cond_aud` (3 factors:CA,EA,NoA). As I used sliding contrast which means that the model summary only gave me the interactions of `location: CA-EA`, `location: EA-NoA`. To test the interaction of `location: NoA-CA`, I used emmeans function without adjustment:

`contrast(emmeans(lmerwp2,~location*cond_aud),interaction=c("pairwise","pairwise"),adjust="none")`

And results show a significant interaction between `E-words` and `CA -NoA`as below:

[image]

However, follow-up pairwise comparisons show that there is no simple effect of `location`(i.e., E-words) in `CA` or `NoA` (see below), although the direction of effects are opposite. How could the interaction be significant when no simple effects are significant? Or should I just report the different directions of simple effects?

[image]

Comment: Could you please include more details on the original linear mixed model, not just the abstraction from it done via `emmeans`? The outputs you show say "results are averaged over the levels of: cond_vd," a predictor not in your calls to `emmeans`. I'm not sure that will matter for an answer to your question, but it might be informative in providing a context.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for that to happen. Try to remember that the goal of statistical analysis is to explain the patterns in the data, not to obtain asterisks.

Comment: @Russ Lenth,just to clarify, the summary of my lmer model (```dv ~ location * cond_vd * cond_aud + (cond_vd + cond_aud |  pp) + (1 | worditem)``` showed that there is no significant interaction of ```location:cond_vd:cond_aud (CA-NoA)```, which means that the interaction of  ```location: cond_aud (CA-NoA)```  is not modulated by the variable of ```cond_vd```. So in this case, based on the reports I put in the post, I should just report  that the effect of location was in different directions in ```CA``` and ```NoA```. Did I understood it accurately?

Comment: That is not a correct interpretation. Being unable to prove there is an effect is not the same as proving that there is no effect.

Comment: @Russ Lenth, I get your point. But in this case why would you suggest as the best way to report such interaction?